# Unable to SSH a remote machine as a root using Paramiko library of python

Tags: python, authentication, ssh, root, paramiko

I am trying to establish an SSH connection to a remote machine as a root. I get a series of errors when I execute the SSH command:

```
ssh.connect(host, port=22, username=username, password=password)
```

Errors:

```
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password) File  
"C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 307, in  
connect look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)     

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py",
line 519, in _auth   raise saved_exception      

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 510, in _auth
self._transport.auth_password(username, password) 

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1168, in
auth _password  return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)  

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line
208, in wa it_for_response      raise e    

paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

I can SSH the same remote machine as a normal user. This error comes only when I try to login as a root. Please provide a solution. Here is my code I have written.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()    
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  
    try:        
        ssh.connect(host, port=22, username=username, password=password)  
        print ('connecting to wag.... '+host)      
    except:  
        print ('Cannot SSH WAG : '+host+'Check the connection or parameters supplied')
```

Comment: If the `PermitRootLogin` is set to `no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine you will not be able to log in as root via ssh. Can you check that first?

Comment: Can you connect as root using a standalone SSH client (e.g. the OpenSSH `ssh` command-line client)?

Comment: I checked the sshd_config of the machine and PermitRootLogin is set to "YES".

Comment: Hi Martin, I use putty to connect to remote machine and login as normal user, with a special command I enter developer mode and I execute a command "enable-root". Then I close the connection, SSH again the same machine and this time I login as root and it works! Same way I programmed but my program fails to login as root. Normal login happens.

Comment: from a security perspective I'd highly advice against implementing this kind of *backdoor*. anyway, there must be something wrong with your proprietary 'enable-root' script. try enabling paramiko debug logging. compare pcaps of putty with paramiko. where does it hang/raise an exception? do you still get the auth failed exception? check your ssh config.

Answer (score 0):

Sample script that worked for me :

```
import paramiko, socket
def check_hostname(host_name, pw_r):

        print ("Checking hostname :"+str(host_name))
        file_output = open('output_file','a')
        file_success = open('success_file','a')
        file_failed = open('failed_file','a')
        file_error = open('error_file','a')
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
          ssh.connect(host_name, username='root', password=pw_r, timeout=5)
          print ("Success")
          file_success.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_success.close()
          file_output.write("success: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_output.close()

          # printing output if required from remote machine
          #stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname&&uptime")
          #for line in stdout.readlines():
           # print (line.strip())

        except paramiko.SSHException:
                print ("error")
                file_failed.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_failed.close()
                file_output.write("failed: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_output.close()
                #quit()
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError:
                print ("might be windows------------")
                file_output.write("failed: " + str(host_name + "\n"))
                file_output.close()
                file_failed.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_failed.close()
                #quit()
        except socket.gaierror:
          print ("wrong hostname/dns************")
          file_output.write("error: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_output.close()
          file_error.write(str(host_name + "\n"))
          file_error.close()

        except socket.timeout:
           print ("No Ping %%%%%%%%%%%%")
           file_output.write("error: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
           file_output.close()
           file_error.write(str(host_name + "\n"))
           file_error.close()

        ssh.close()

host_name = input("Enter Hostname: ")
pw_r = input("Enter password: ")
check_hostname(host_name,pw_r)
```